# audio playback and multitasking

Tags: audio, multitasking

I have been wondering how an operating system can play audio continuously with no interruptions while other programs are running.

Sometimes when intensive program is run i can notice the music stops for a second, maybe a few at times.

But generally I can listen to music while playing an intensive game.
How does the operating system manage to play it with (almost) no interruptions at all?

Answer (score 0):

It gives a higher priority to audio threads.

Android SDK says that normal applications can not change to this (higher) priority: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO

Comment: So is it just so fast that my ear cannot notice it?

Comment: @Apeee OS (almost) never makes audio thread yield in favor of other threads so the music plays continiously (so you can dance all night)

Answer (score 0):

Audio is played back by hardware. The software, including the OS, is responsible for transferring chunks of audio, called "buffers" to the hardware at semi-regular intervals. As long as the hardware receives the next chunk before the last chunk runs out, playback is continuous.

I have a diagram of this on my talk slides:

http://blog.bjornroche.com/2011/11/slides-from-fundamentals-of-audio.html